# What does the B I G mean on a college American football field?

Tags: american-football

I was watching this first half shut-out between Michigan and Ohio and on the field there is B I G painted on the field. The paint is white, the B is just outlined while the I G is solid white.

What is this meant to represent?

[image: From https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ohio_State_vs.Michigan_football_2013_04(Ohio_State_on_offense).jpg]
Michael Barera photo

Answer (score 5):

This is the logo of the [Big Ten Conference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Ten_Conference) of which both Michigan State and Ohio are members; the branding has the "B" in a different style from the "I"/"1" and the "G".

Comment: B1G also does double duty as "B 10".  Adding the reason for the stylization differences would improve this answer.